# How to always redirect to HTTPS using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, web

I am currently working on my very own homepage and got into some trouble with the **automate redirection to HTTPS**.

I got a few domains.

- `mydomain.de` --> directs to the root of my webspace, where my homepages is.
- `mydomain.com`, `mydomain.net`, `mydomain.info` -> Redirect to `mydomain.de`

> `mydomain.de` got an **SSL Certificate**, the other 3 don't have one.

**My Question is:** How must I configure my .htaccess that every time I call my website using one of the four domains, how to ensure that always HTTPS is used?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds pretty straight forward:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,END]
```

Note that no browser will allow a connection using ssl to any of the hostnames you do *not* have a ssl certificate for, for obvious reasons. No way around that. Above rules will only redirect non-ssl requests, except for the hostname you *do* have a valid ssl certificate for. It definitely does make sense to use ssl for *all* host names. Certificates are free these days...

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:// www.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```